# unable to send large commands to expect send

Tags: tcl, expect

unable to send large commands to expect send coomand

```
awk -F\\\" '\"07/12/2013 01:12:49\" < \$2 && \$2 < \"07/12/2013 01:44:49\"' /home/user/code/testDir/Log/alarm.log
```

it gives output

I am trying to send this command to expect i am getting syntax error,

some where i heard that expect accept only 27 character length command only, is it correct?.

I tried with workaround to split command into multiple sends it works, but i need to automated every thing without human interaction.

```
expect "$prompt" {
    send "awk -F\\\" '\"07/12/2013 01:12:49\" < \$2 "
    send_user "...Press"
    expect_user -re ".*\[\r\n]+"
    send "  && \$2 < \"07/12/2013 01:50:39\"'"
    send_user "...Press"
    expect_user -re ".*\[\r\n]+"
    send " alarm.log\r\r"
}
```

Comment: I solved this issue by running this script on linux/unix.

Answer (score 2):

Expect has no such limit

```
set command {awk -F'"' '"07/12/2013 01:12:49" < $2 && $2 < "07/12/2013 01:44:49"' /home/user/code/testDir/Log/alarm.log}
send "$command\r"
```

Comment: yes there is no limit when we are using linux/unix if using windows os i am getting this error.